# Problem with Google Cloud Platform: "AccessDeniedException: 403 The project to be billed is associated with a closed billing account."

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I created an account on Google Cloud Platform and I have successfully activated the billing account, created a project and its bucket.
I need to copy a long data set from another company's bucket to my bucket.
I received the following permissions from this company for the bucket I need to copy:

- Storage Administrator;
- Storage Object Administrator.

The command I use from the console to copy the data has this structure:

`gsutil -m cp -L cp.log -r gs://old_bucket/data gs://my_new_bucket/`

However, running the command, I get the following error message for each file I try to copy:

`AccessDeniedException: 403 The project to be billed is associated with a closed billing account.`

and at the end of the file transfer, the message:

`CommandException: 160749 files/objects could not be transferred.`

To check that the command used is correct I also tried to copy the data from another person's bucket to my bucket and I succeed.

I've been going crazy with this problem for several days and I can't find the solution, please help me!

Thank you!

Comment: The error message states the billing account is **closed**. If you reactivated the billing account, check if there is an error processing your debit/credit card. If you continue to have problems contact Google Cloud Billing Support https://cloud.google.com/support/billing

Comment: @john-hanley -- I think your comment should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error message states the billing account is closed. If you reactivated the billing account, check if there is an error processing your debit/credit card. If you continue to have problems contact [Google Cloud Billing Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
My billing account is working fine, I have successfully created a bucket and copied the data from my colleague's bucket.
All the problems are about copying data from the company's bucket (on which I have permissions, but I am not the owner).

Comment: @Nicola - If you do not have a problem with your billing account, then why do you receive the error message **The project to be billed is associated with a closed billing account**? You have a billing account problem. Some services will work at the free-tier level for some operations and require billing for other operations.